# Problem in reading an incremental encoder simulink

Tags: ros, matlab, differential-drive, encoder

I'm trying to read an encoder to receive a velocity value. The robot is a differential drive robot based on ROS, to which I can send commands to the right and left wheels ranging from 0 to 1. Where 0 means the wheel is stationary and 1 indicates maximum speed. The encoder sends me these data:

```
Header

Stamp

Sec : 1703272814

Nsec : 334324598

Seq : 7460

FrameId : ducklorean/right_wheel_axis

Data : 69844

Resolution : 135

Type :
```

I have tried two approach:
The first one is on the Data (that increase) using a zero order hold and a derivative, and I actually get a function that seems to be proportional to the speed that I use as input.
The only problem is that for "high speed" like 0.8 , 0.9 I get a function that more or less is there. but for low speed like 0.1 I get a function that is near 0.2 and for 0.2 as input I get 0.3.
so for low speed is not accurate at all.
[image]

the second approach is to use a delay (1/z) and then subract new_data-delaydata but also this seems not to be working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My concern here is that you're getting encoder positions from ROS but you're doing differentiation in Matlab. If you have timing differences between the two then you're liable to get really wrong values.

My proposal would be to use the timestamp you get from the message. When you do this, you're getting elapsed time from the same source that captured the encoder reading. It's been quite a while since I wrote Matlab, and I don't currently have a license, but I believe the following code should work:

```
function speed = GetSpeedFromStampedEncoder(encoder_count, timestamp_s, timestamp_ns)
  persistent previous_stamp;
  persistent previous_encoder_count;
  
  current_stamp = timestamp_s + (timestamp_ns/1e9);
  
  if isempty(previous_stamp)
    previous_stamp = current_stamp;
    previous_encoder_count = encoder_count;
    speed = 0;
    return;
  end

  % You'll probably need to check for wrapping encoder values, something like:
  %
  % if encoder_count < previous_encoder_count
  %   previous_encoder_count = previous_encoder_count - full_encoder_count;
  % end
  % 
  % where full_encoder_count is whatever the maximum reportable value is from your encoder.

  % You didn't mention what the resolution value is, but you will want to 
  % convert it to an angle to get a meaningful speed output. If I  assume
  % that it's counts per revolution, then you'll get something like:
  %
  % encoder_rev = encoder_count / resolution;
  % previous_encoder_rev = previous_encoder_count / resolution;
  %
  % and then you convert to radians by multiplying by 2*pi (convert
  % to degrees by multiplying by 360):
  %
  % encoder_rad = encoder_rev * (2 * pi);
  % previous_encoder_rad = previous_encoder_rev * (2 * pi);
  %
  % encoder_deg = encoder_rev * (360);
  % previous_encoder_deg = previous_encoder_rev * (360);
  %
  % then calculate your speed in rad/s or deg/s, depending on what you want. 
  
  speed = (encoder_unit - previous_encoder_unit) / (current_stamp - previous_stamp);

  previous_stamp = current_stamp;
  previous_encoder_count = encoder_count;
end
```

I wrote this, posted it, then realized I didn't take your `resolution` into account, so I added a section of comments in there about converting your counts to engineering units. Up to you if you want to convert to radians per second, degrees per second, or include a wheel radius and convert directly to a linear speed.

I wrote the comment assuming your resolution is counts per revolution, but it could be anything; you'll need to check your datasheet. Good luck!